# Strange behavior of pasting into Julia 0.5.1 REPL on Windows

Tags: windows, julia, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using Julia 0.5.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 REPL on Windows 7. When I copy this code to clipboard:

```
function e4(N = 1000)   
    nMax = 0
    for x = 1:N, y = x:N
            n = x*y 
            s = string(n)
            s == reverse(s) || continue
            nMax = max(n, nMax)
    end 
    nMax
end
```

and paste it to the REPL, I'm getting:

```
julia> function e4(N = 1000)
           nMax = 0
           for x = 1:N, y = x:N
                   n = x*yield
                   s = string(n)
                   s == reverse(s) || continue
                   nMax = max(n, nMax)
           end
           nMax
       end
e4 (generic function with 2 methods)
```

where the second occurrence of `y` is replaced with `yield`. Any clues what magic is going on here? BTW, pasting this code to other Windows application or Julia notebook works fine.

Comment: Can't replicate this behaviour myself. But if you were to paste a <tab> then `y` would autocomplete to `yield`.

Comment: where are you copying from?

Comment: @AlexanderMorley There was a tab behind the second `y`, which got autocompleted to `yield`. Thank you, for pointing me in the right direction. If you write an answer, I will accept it.